# Can't Seem to Solve This Parametric Arclength Problem

Tags: integration, parametric

I'm working on an arclength question right, now, and I'm consistently landing very close to the answer but not on it. I'm trying to find the arclength of the following:

$x = 6e^tcos(t) ; y = 6e^tsin(t) ; z = 17e^t$ from t = 0 to t = 1

I know that the arc length is the integral from 0 to 1 of v(t)

So here's what I've done:

$x' = -6(e^t)sin(t)$

$y' = 6(e^t)cos(t)$

$z' = 17e^t$

And then finding the squares of these values:

$x'^2 = 36(e^{2t})sin(t)^2$

$y'^2 = 36(e^{2t})cos(t)^2$

$z'^2 = 289e^{2t}$

And now that I have those individually, I add them under a square root. This is where things go wrong.

$\sqrt{36(e^{2t})sin(t)^2 + 36(e^{2t})cos(t)^2 + 289e^{2t}}$

$\sqrt{e^{2t}(36sin(t)^2 + 36cos(t)^2 + 289)}$

$\sqrt{e^{2t}(36(sin(t)^2 + cos(t)^2) + 289)}$

$\sqrt{e^{2t}(36 + 289)}$

$e^{t}\sqrt{36 + 289}$

$e^{t}\sqrt{325}$

So my method tells me to take the integral of this. But according to the book, I should actually be taking the integral of $e^{t}\sqrt{361}$, or $e^{t}\sqrt{289 + 36 + 36}$.

In other words, somewhere in my method I'm losing an additional 6$^2$, but for the life of me I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Jesus, yes, you're right, this is what starts happening after 12 hour study marathons. Thank you for the help, I see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation of the derivatives $x'$ and $y'$ are incorrect. You should have $$x'(t) = (6 e^t \cos t)' = 6 e^t (\cos t - \sin t),$$ so $$x'(t)^2 = 6 e^{2t} (1 - 2 \sin t \cos t).$$
This and a similar computation for $y(t)$ give
$$x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 = 12 e^{2t},$$
which accounts exactly for the deviation from the given solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you take $x'$ and and $y'$ you forgot to use the product rule.  If $x=6e^t\cos(t), x'=6(e^t)'\cos(t)+6e^t(\cos (t))'=6e^t\cos(t)-6e^t\sin (t)$